# Closing main form doesn't finish process (only some computers)

Tags: vb.net

The problem is happening on 2 of the company's computers and on a client computer, but we can not identify a pattern.

I was able to reproduce the error using a simple program that only opens an OpenFileDialog. The program must be run by the generated executable itself (NOT by Debug) and it is still running in the background even after closing. Below is the code of the program, along with a link to download the project and a video demonstrating the error.

Code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private ofdAbrir As Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ofdAbrir = New Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
        ofdAbrir.ShowDialog()
        ofdAbrir.Dispose()
        ofdAbrir = Nothing
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see in the code above, I only have one form, so it is not the case that some form remains open and it is also not related to threads running since none is created.

To reproduce the problem, click on Button1, cancel the OpenFileDialog and try to close the form (clicking on X). The form apparently will close, but you will see at task manager that it still running. The big mystery is that this problem does not happens in all computers.

Video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sfdVUGQlwYNCQkl1Ht-cJSOb4433sqnT

Project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1d4oJYUjaaZ9xnRj4CX3HXOQPqwMZmE0V

Comment: Visual Studio window > Project > Project properties > Shut down mode > Last window close

Comment: Thank's for the comment but I've already tried it and isn't work.

Comment: then just add `Application.Exit` on the form's closing event

Comment: zack raiyan, look this test adding Application.Exit, End and Process.Kill (finish process but i don't see why i need it and don't want to use this) -> https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pDxeVYxSw9U1tTCDrGDxshBjUFaAAGRe

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the problem, but how about using this method:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Using ofdAbrir As New Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
        ofdAbrir.ShowDialog()
        MsgBox(ofdAbrir.FileName)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: rheitzman, the problem is not the method of using OpenFileDialog and i knew that it will be difficult to reproduce because here in my company i reproduced only in 2 computers at an universe of 30. Look the last test adding Application.Exit, End and Process.Kill (finish process but i don't see why i need it and don't want to use this) ->https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pDxeVYxSw9U1tTCDrGDxshBjUFaAAGRe

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the video u posted...It is not your application that is running rather it is the `vsHost.exe` that is running :)...The problem shouldn't occur if u run the app outside visual studio.

If the problem is still there,just disable **Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging** from Tools > Options > Debugging > Uncheck Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging

Also u can disable **Visual Studio hosting service** from Project > Project Properties > Uncheck **Enable the Visual Studio hosting service**

Comment: zack raiyan, please look again and you will see that i runned the app outside visual studio by double click at executable and i have to force on task manager to finalize the Teste.exe and not the Teste.vsHost.exe